# Multiply cited reference with pages

Tags: cross-referencing

How do I create a multiply references with pages?

For example:

(author year: **page**; author year: **page**) ?

Comment: If you don't add more elements, I doubt anyone can help you...

Comment: In order to help you we would need to know what package you use for citing, what style (if any) you use, what commands you use to get a citation... It will help us if you prepare a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) to show us what you've got so far.

Comment: If nickie's answer helped you, you might want to accept it; if it did not satisfy you, it would be a good idea to provide more information for us to go by.

Answer (score 4):

I interpret the question as follows: "How can I cite multiple references **in the same** `\cite` command (so they are enclosed in the same pair of brackets), providing page numbers for all of them?"

---

AFAIK, this cannot be done with LaTeX's standard `\cite` command.  If there's only one reference, `\cite`'s optional argument can be used for this purpose, e.g. `\cite[pp.~10--20]{dragon-book}` but this does not work for multiple references.

Here's two possible solutions using additional packages:

1. Using the [`amsref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs), this can be done quite easily:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsrefs}
   \begin{document}

   Make sure to read the required material
   \citelist{%
     \cite{gunter-1992-splst}*{pp.~10--20}%
     \cite{tennent-1991-spl}*{pp.~30--40}%
   }.

   \bibliography{semantics}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Similarly, using the [`biblatex` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{biblatex}

   \renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
   \addbibresource{semantics.bib}

   \begin{document}
   Make sure to read the required material
   \cites[pp.~10--20]{gunter-1992-splst}%
         [pp.~30--40]{tennent-1991-spl}.

   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```

In both cases, `semantics.bib` should contain something like:

```
@Book{gunter-1992-splst,
  author={C. A. Gunter},
  title={Semantics of Programming Languages: Structures and Techniques},
  publisher={MIT Press},
  address={Cambridge, MA},
  year={1992},
  series={Foundations of Computing Series}
}

@Book{tennent-1991-spl,
  author={R. D. Tennent},
  title={Semantics of Programming Languages},
  publisher={Prentice Hall},
  year={1991},
  address={Englewood Cliffs, NJ}
}
```

and in both cases the result looks something like:

[image: result]

Comment: Note that in `biblatex` there is no need to prefix the page(s) with `pp.~`, that is done automatically by `biblatex` (depending on your style and localisation: some styles omit the `pp.` part).